# onEdit trigger works only for real users

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, triggers

I have a Google Apps Script project with an `onEdit` trigger function that performs certain actions whenever a user edits a Google Sheet. However, I also need this function to run when edits are made programmatically by a Cloud Function that I deployed on GCP, Because the `onEdit` trigger function works only for real users(me and my colleagues) but not for the edits made by the cloud function.

Any insights / workaround on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It only generates triggers on user edits.

Comment: That is the way it was designed to operate.  There is no workaround.

Comment: How are edits made programmatically, API call?

Comment: @TheWizEd yes exactly(in this case *API call* my service account write to my sheet and this doesn't count as an edit)

Comment: Why not duplicate what the `onEdit(e)` does in the API request?